# trigger to create parent element and retrieve id in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have created the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.teams (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE
) WITH (OIDS = FALSE);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.submissions (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    team_id INTEGER REFERENCES public.teams NOT NULL,
    records_num INTEGER NOT NULL,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
) WITH (OIDS = FALSE);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.predictions (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    submission_id INTEGER REFERENCES public.submissions NOT NULL,
    customer INTEGER REFERENCES public.real NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    billing NUMERIC(20, 2) NOT NULL
) WITH (OIDS = FALSE);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.real (
    customer INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    billing NUMERIC(20, 2) NOT NULL
) WITH (OIDS = FALSE);
```

The relation for submissions-predictions is one-to-many; users will submit predictions in packets of 1000 rows that should get the same submission id.

I am trying to create a trigger that runs BEFORE INSERT ON predictions that creates a submissions row. This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_submission() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO submissions(team_id, records_num, timestamp)
    VALUES (1, 1, '2018-04-21 00:00:00'); /*example values, need to fill with dynamically assigned ones, specially for records_num and team_id*/
    RETURN NULL;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
DROP TRIGGER trigger_submission ON public.predictions;
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_submission BEFORE INSERT ON predictions
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_submission();
```

So, my questions are:

1. How do I go about retrieving the newly created submissions.id for the row inserted by the trigger, in order to add it to all the rows inserted in predictions by the user? Do I have to run another trigger AFTER INSERT for this?

EDIT: to clarify following @bignose answer, the sequence of events would go like this:

User inserts 1000 rows into public.predictions:

```
INSERT INTO predictions(customer, date, billing)
VALUES
(1, '2018-01-05', 543.42),
(4, '2018-04-02', 553.21),
...
(423, '2019-11-18', 38.87) /* 1000th row */
```

He does not know which submission_id to insert in those rows and indeed, the submissions row for this packet of predictions doesn't exist yet so a trigger runs before to create a row in submissions that would execute something like this:

```
INSERT INTO public.submisssions(team_id, records_num, timestamp)
VALUES (
4, /* I will need something to retrieve team_id here */
1000, /* I will need something to count the rows of the insert that triggered this */
NOW() /* convert to timestamp */
)
```

This last query should return the public.submission.id value that it has just created to the insert the user requested so that it ends up being something like this:

```
INSERT INTO predictions(customer, date, billing)
VALUES
(@submission_id, 1, '2018-01-05', 543.42),
(@submission_id, 4, '2018-04-02', 553.21),
...
(@submission_id, 423, '2019-11-18', 38.87) /* 1000th row */
```

Where @submission_id should be the value retrieved from the trigger (and the some for all the 1000 rows)

2. How could I count the rows inserted by the user to use them as value for submissions.records_num?
3. How could I retrieve team.id to insert during the trigger execution, assuming I know team.name beforehand?

Thank you!
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

A trigger function, when used for a row-level trigger, [has access to the old and new state of the table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER).

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_submission() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO submissions(team_id, records_num, timestamp)
    VALUES (NEW.foo, NEW.bar, '2018-04-21 00:00:00');
    RETURN NULL;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It's not clear from the description, which fields you expect to retrieve from the row that triggers this function. So you'll need to substitute `NEW.foo` and `NEW.bar` with field references in the `NEW` row state.

Comment: You are right, it's not clear from my question what I expect to retrieve, let me edit it.